# How to formulate different conditions in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am struggling in Excel with the following task:

- Column O: Type of proposal: 3 options - Easy (<5 WD) / Medium (<10 WD) / Complex (<20WD)
- Column T: RfP receive date
- Column V: Proposal sent date
- Column W: Offer Time in Workdays
- Column X: Approval lead time (30 days)
- Column Y: Proposal approved by xx (date)

---

- In column W I am having now the following formula: `=NETWORKDAYS(T3;TODAY();0)`
- In column X I am having now the following formula: `=NETWORKDAYS(V3;TODAY();0)`

What I like to have is the following:

[image]

Column W "Offer time in workdays should do the following:

1. Calculate the number of working days from the entered date in column T "RFP receive date
2. Depending on the value in column O "Type of proposal, a color formatting should be performed:

   - If the value is "Easy (<5 WD) the color should be red when 5 working days are passed. It should be amber if the working days are 3. It should be green till the 3rd working day.
   - If the value is "Medium (<10 WD) the color should be red when 10 working days are passed. It should be amber if the working days are 7. It should be green till the 6th working day.
   - If the value is "Complex (<20 WD) the color should be red when 20 working days are passed. It should be amber if the working days are 15. It should be green till the 14th working day.
   - When the date is filled in column V " Proposal sent date", the column W " Offer time in workday" should calculate the working days until the entered value in column V.

For column X " approval lead time (30 days) the following should happen:

1. Calculate the number of days (so not working days) from the entered date in column V "Proposal sent to xx date"
2. A color formatting should be performed:

   - If the number of days are 30, the color should be red.
   - It should be amber if the days are 25.
   - It should be green till the 24th day.
3. When the date is filled in column Y " Proposal approved by xx", the column X " Approval lead time (30 days)" should calculate the days until the entered value in column Y.

Comment: It seems you expect us to do your job which is off-topic here. Good questions demonstrate reasonable effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @Mate Juhasz, thank you for the reply and I understand your point. As I am not that good in Excel and tried looking on internet I could only find solution for only one part like I mentioned for: 
In column W I am having now the following formula: =NETWORKDAYS(T3;TODAY();0)
However, I am trying if it is possible to combine multiple conditions and believe me I tried to combine it and everytime I am getting the error, so I was a little bit hopeless and posted my question here. If I will not get the support I will leave it as my current formula, so other features will not be working for me.

Comment: You say you tried to combine different conditions. *How*? Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1445502/edit) instead of adding information in comments.